# Bitmap too big as3

Tags: actionscript-3, image, zip, arrays

In AS3, I am loading a png from a zip file (nochump's zip library through ByteArray to Loader). The png can be up to 45k pixels wide but only 120 tall. This creates a problem in flash, as images can only be ~8000 pixels wide. A possible solution would be to split the images into 6 columns somehow. This would probably need to be done in the ByteArray state, because the limitation is in Bitmap and Loader. Would this even be possible?

Comment: You'd better split this outside of SWF. PNG decoders aren't common for ActionScript because usually it just can load it with Loader.

Comment: Yeah, alxx, I will probably do this, since I have access to the images ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should use Alchemy to decode such a large file and put it in a `Byterray`. It looks like it has been done for JPEG, PNG shouldn't be very different!

http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/alchemy-loading-large-jpeg-images

Comment: I am going to go ahead and pre-split the images, but I will keep this in mind for next time. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

All things are *possible* since you have the bytes. However this would require you to write a **complete png library in actionscript.** PNG is a very complicated and sophisticated compressed image format, so you can't just shred the image into blocks by copying portions of the ByteArray.

So really, the answer is **no, it is not possible**. Sorry.

If it was an uncompressed BMP on the other hand you would be in with a chance. However I suspect that if you are able to change the format of the file, it would be easier to pre-split the image into columns.